# Jdbc Paradox Encrypted files

Tags: java, encryption, jdbc, paradox

I need to access some paradox files from JDBC.

Since the most complete library is not free I manage to read the files using a Odbc-Jdbc bridge [see](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html): I create a datasource in windows using the paradox drivers and connect to the source using the jdbc-odbc driver.

My problem is that the files are encrypted, and I can't find a way to proved in the datasource url or in the jdbc url.

I can remove the encryption using the [Paradox Data Editor](http://www.mitec.cz/pde.html) but I have to open one file at time.

Does someone know:

1. A Java API that can access the encrypted files?
2. A command line tools that can remove the encryption
3. An API (not only Java) that can remove the encryption from the paradox files.

Thanks

Comment: what type of encryption do the files use ?

Comment: Actually I don't know how to retrieve this information. I understand that with paradox you can set a password on the table [see](http://prestwood.com/ASPSuite/kb/document_view.asp?qid=101193)  and that are different types of encryptions  'DES', 'TRIDES', or 'BLOWFISH. Using [Paradox Data Editor](http://www.mitec.cz/pde.html) I can remove the password protection entirely without provide any password, but I could not get infromation about the encryption type.

Comment: Have you tried opening the files with "universal passwords"?
http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2004/a/bltip0304_4.htm